# MongoDB Aggregate - Group by month on a field with timestamp(int)

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate

I am unable to aggregate a collection with month wise grouping on field with value as timestamp.

```
Collection(Dummy):
{
   "created_at": 1232341243
}, {...}, ...
```

Now if I want to aggregate the documents of this collection on month using $month it throws the following error:

```
db.getCollection('dummy').aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": {"$month": "$created_at"}}}])

Error message
"errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type int to Date",
```

Version of MongoDB: 3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by seeing what types of input [$month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) supports:

> A Date, a Timestamp, or an ObjectID.

So for Mongo version 4.0+ you can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) to convert a valid (number) ts or a valid date string into a `Date` object like so:

```
{"$group": {"_id": {"$month": {"$toDate":"$created_at"}}}}
```

As you're using an earlier Mongo version and don't have access to this function You can use a "hacky" aggregation using [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) as when it get's a number and a date type it will return a date type.

The only caveat is that you'll need to convert your timestamp (which is represented with seconds from epoch 0) to miliseconds. i.e multiply by a 1000, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$month": {
                '$add': [
                    datetime(1970, 1, 1),
                    {'$multiply': ["$created_at", 1000]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the "created_at" timestamp to date using "addFields" stage,

```
{
$addFields: {
    convertedDate: {"$toDate":"$created_at"}
  }
}
```

after that, you can do further operations. So finally your query for aggregation will be something like,
For Version 3.6

```
[
  {
   '$project': {
      "convertedDate": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$created_at" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'month': {
        '$month': '$convertedDate'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$year': '$convertedDate'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'month': '$month', 
        'year': '$year'
      }, 
      'total': {
        '$sum': 1
      }, 
      'month': {
        '$first': '$month'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$first': '$year'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

For Version 4+

```
[
  {
   '$addFields': {
    'convertedDate': {"$toDate":"$created_at"}
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'month': {
        '$month': '$convertedDate'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$year': '$convertedDate'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'month': '$month', 
        'year': '$year'
      }, 
      'total': {
        '$sum': 1
      }, 
      'month': {
        '$first': '$month'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$first': '$year'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Unrecognized expression '$toDate', I guess it is available from mongo 4 and I am on 3.6

Comment: For version 3.6 you can replaced addField Stage to ```{'$project:{
      "convertedDate": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$created_at" ] }
}}```  . You can check my answer which I updated